# Analyzing Windows 7 Kernel crash dump on Windows 10

Tags: windows

I am new to Windows Kernel and driver crash debugging. I am curious to know whether it is possible to analyze a Windows 7 Kernel crash dump using WinDBG on a Windows 10 machine. Actually I need to analyze a crash dump which was reported on a Windows 7 machine, but I have Windows 10 machine only. I am doubtful about the compatibility of the Symbols. It would be really helpful if someone can guide me on this.

Comment: I don't think it will make any difference.  The crash dump contains the information windbg needs to find the right symbols, it doesn't just assume that it is the same OS you're running on.

Comment: you can analyze it on any machine. of course need use correct symbols. before open crash dump - `File -> Symbol File Path...` or `Ctrl+S` and in dialog enter symbol path, where you prefer download and use symbols for this win7. say `srv*c:\win7*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols` for example. read more - [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/symbol-path)